# Issue with ReportViewer on Windows Azure websites (WAWS)

Tags: azure, reportviewer, azure-web-app-service

In one of my project i have used reportviewer control to display reports on web pages and at time of uploading on Azure I have followed the steps mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg430128.aspx)

After uploading when i runs that report web page then it's giving me below error

> ```
> An error occurred during local report processing.
> The definition of the report 'Reports\Report1.rdlc' is invalid.
> An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing.
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, >    
> Version=10.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
> ```

What should be cause of this?

**Update**:

I have added following 2 dlls as shown in below snap
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll (10.0)
 
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll (10.0)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long research i found solution of my problem from [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/08/17/10051010.aspx)

The problem with missing reference of below dlls

- Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
- Microsoft.RevportViewer.DataVisualization.dll

but after instaling i could not found those dlls in **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL**

But there is assembly files available in this path **C:\Windows\assembly**
then i have added those dlls using VS2010 directly as shown in below fig.

[image]

And it's worked!

Answer (score 1):

What is the version of ReportViewer you have used in this project and would you please specify how many and which one Reference DLL you have included in your project? This will help to ensure that you have included all the DLL properly in your project. You must use Report Viewer SP1 which is compatible with Azure DB, and the same SP1 language pack.

I would suggest FTP to your website and verify that you do have all the DLL uploaded correctly  as you configure in your project. This is the best way to check in Windows Azure Websites if all the configured files made it to file server.

Comment: I have added more information in question, please look at that,

Comment: Arun, I haven't used 10.0 version of ReportViewer so I am not sure why u are getting this error. I am using Report Viewer 2010 SP1 (11.0) and it is tested to work so I may suggest you to try using 11.0 and see if   that helps you.

Comment: I have installed it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=6610, still i can see 10.0 version withing it's DLL..

Comment: I do have RV SP1 and the version I got is 11.0. I don't have VS2010 instead I am using VS2012 but do not believe this a reason. Your best bet to use 11.0.

Comment: Okay, Is there any way to use 11.0 RV SP1 in VS2010?

Comment: I found solution with 10.0 version,please check my answer.